# Is $(\mathbb{R},\tau_B)$ a separable space?

Tags: general-topology

> Is $(\mathbb{R},\tau_B)$ a separable space?
>
> $\tau_b$ is the topology generated by
>
> $$\mathcal{B} = \{ \ [a,b) \ \ : \ \  a,b\in\mathbb{R}, \ a<b\}$$

I guess it's not separable because I can't think in any A such that $\overline{A}=A\cup A'=\mathbb{R}$ being A countable(I think adding the limit points to a countable set can not turn it in uncountable set). I guess it is easy to probe that problem by contradiction. But I can't really find a way to demonstrate with math what I have in my head. Why? It happens to me a lot of times.

Maybe I'm wrong and it is separable. Help.

Comment: Hint: What is the closure of the rationals?

Comment: If "adding the limit points to a countable set can not turn it [into an] uncountable set", then how can any uncountable space be separable?

Comment: I think I can't see easily the closure of a set when it has no graphical representation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The space is separable because the set of all rational numbers is a countable dense set. Every basic open set, and therefore every nonempty open set, contains a rational number.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is nonempty and open in topology $\tau_B$, then $\operatorname{Int}_{\text{met}} ( U )$ (the interior of $U$ with respect to the usual metric/order topology on $\mathbb{R}$) must also be nonempty. (You can see this by just looking at the sets in the base: if $a < b$, then $\operatorname{Int}_{\text{met}} ( [a , b) ) = ( a , b ) \neq \varnothing$.)

Because of this connection, we can directly apply the fact that the usual metric/order topology on $\mathbb{R}$ is separable to conclude that $\tau_B$ is also separable.